# Python: Removing specific char while writing in .csv file

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I need to write a dictionary with lists as values into a CSV.
Input looks like:

```
d = {'a': [1.11, 2.22, 3.33],
     'b': [4.44, 5.55, 6.66],
     'c': [7.77, 8.88, 9.99]}
```

The output should look like:

```
a    1.11    2.22    3.33
b    4.44    5.55    6.66
c    7.77    8.88    9.99
```

My code is

```
with open('Test.csv', 'w') as f:
    for key in d.keys():
        f.write("%s,%s\n"%(key,d[key]))
```

Which outputs:

```
a    [1.11    2.22    3.33]
b    [4.44    5.55    6.66]
c    [7.77    8.88    9.99]
```

How can I amend my code to remove the brackets upon storing into the csv file? I know I can go through the file later and remove the brackets but I would like to do it before or while I'm writing to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
for key, values in d.items():
    f.write("%s %s\n"%(key, " ".join([str(v) for v in values])))
```

You can't just `join()` the d[key] because they are numbers and have to be converted to strings.

However I do not really think that you want it to be space separated as you have shown since you said you wanted a CSV. If you want it comma separated, then it would be:

```
for key, values in d.items():
    f.write("%s, %s\n"%(key, ", ".join([str(v) for v in values])))
```

[edit]

I should clarify why you were getting the '[' and ']' in your original code.

In your code, the contents of d[key] is a list. When you tell python to print a list, it prints the elements of the list separated by commas and wrapped with opening and closing square brackets to show that the thing being printed is a list.

The answer avoids that by breaking up the list using the

```
for v in values
```

and then putting them back together with the join().

Answer (score 2):

d[key] is a list that you can join with a space character to get the string you want:

```
f.write("%s,%s\n"%(key, " ".join(d[key])))
```

By the way, if you intend to do CSV, have a look at the standard module:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Comment: I edited the question a bit to reflect floats instead of ints. This is the error I got:
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, float found

Comment: This `" ".join(d[key])` will not work because the values in the dict entries are lists of numbers and `join()` needs strings. They need to be converted to string as in my answer.  The suggestion of using the CSV module is a good idea though.

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code, the result is:

```
a,[1, 2, 3]
b,[4, 5, 6]
c,[7, 8, 9]
```

So, this is not the cleanest way, but it works:

```
with open('Test.csv', 'w') as f:
    for key in d.keys():
        f.write("%s"%(key))
        for k in d[key]:
            f.write(" %s"""%k)
        f.write("\n")
```

```
a 1 2 3
b 4 5 6
c 7 8 9
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that I try to remove specific char in a dataframe column.

```py
FILE_PATH = "***.csv"
DONE_PATH = "done.csv"
SPECIFIC_COL = "SPECIFIC_COL"
REMOVE_CHAR = 'Â'

df = pd.read_csv(FILE_PATH,encoding='utf-8')
df[SPECIFIC_COL] = df[SPECIFIC_COL].str.replace(,'')

# Before writing to the csv, check if it exists or not
try: 
    os.remove(DONE_PATH)
except OSError:
    pass

df.to_csv(DONE_PATH)
```